# I've made an animation with CSS (transform) and it resets when the animation ends

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have the following structure, and my problem is that when the animaition ends that is replacing down it just restart, and I was wondering if there's anyway it just stops nad waits in the finle while its hovered, thanks , here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/bd4c5cc7/

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul class="list">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Quienes somos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Servicios</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Flota</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Donde estamos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contacto</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Galeria</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.nav {
    background-color: #A45A52;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.list {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.list li {
    display: inline;
    font-family: MyFont;
    color: white;
    font-size: 26px;
    padding: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.list li:hover {
    background-color: White;
    color: #483C32;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
    -o-transform: translateY(10px);
    transform: translateY(10px);
    border-radius: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Works fine in jsfiddle on Firefox; http://jsfiddle.net/wrpkgcvp/

Comment: it doesn't restart for me (osx / chrome), it just jumps back up, but the rounded border and white background remains...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with transitions/animations:

> [**CSS Transforms Module Level 1**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#terminology)
>
> A transformable element is an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a block-level or [atomic inline-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#x13), or whose display property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption.

Changing the `display` of the list items from `inline` to `inline-block` should fix this.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/dLc2p5q7/)

It seems like there are some inconsistencies across browsers. The behavior you are seeing (where the transition resets) occurs in Chrome/IE11.

FireFox, on the other hand, won't even transition the element at all since it is a non-replacing `inline` level element.

```
.list li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: MyFont;
    color:white;
    font-size:26px;
    padding:20px;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease 0s;
    transition:all 1s ease 0s;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```