# CSS transform moves back after completion

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm not sure if I'm tired or what, but I'm trying to make a little arrow (▶) move from left to right when the user hovers a link.

Here's my CSS:

```
a:after {
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
    content: "▶";
}

a:hover:after {
    transform: translateX(20px);
}
```

When hovering the link the arrow starts to move, but once it has moved 20px to the right it immediately jumps back to its original position even though I'm still hovering the link.

Why is this?

http://jsfiddle.net/tzyorz12/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25594859, and http://stackoverflow.com/a/26327972 .. in your case, here is [the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/rtxok6zn/). Pseudo elements are inline by default.

Comment: I think you will need to add some keyframes to make a smoother transition
but this is a nice hover effect library looks to have the effects you are looking for
[Hover.css](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well apparently I *was* tired. An inline element can't seem to be transformed (reliably at least). Adding `display: inline-block` to the pseudo element solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

you need to modify the layout:

```css
a:after {
  transform: translateX(0) translateY(0);
  content: " ▶";
  display:inline-block;
}

a:hover:after {
  transform:translateX(20px) translateY(0); 
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Foo</a>
```

If you want the arrow to remain at the end of the transition, you may use animation or set a very long transition on unhovered state :

```css
a:after {
  transform: translateX(0) translateY(0);
  transition: transform 10000000s ease-in-out;/* freeze effect on such a long time */
  content: " ▶";
  display:inline-block;
}
a:hover:after {
  transform:translateX(20px) translateY(0); 
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Foo</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out while you were writing this it seems. `display: inline-block` worked.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding `display: inline-block;`

check the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dyaa/tzyorz12/2/

Answer (score 0):

```css
a:after {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(0) translateY(0);
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
    content: "▶";
}

a:hover:after {
    transform: translateX(20px);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Foaaao</a>
<br>
<a href="#">F0o</a>
<br>
<a href="#">F0asdsdo</a>
<br>
<a href="#">F0gggggggo</a>
```

Comment: Not really an answer to the original question.

Comment: I don't want to position it absolutely tho do I. I want it to appear in flow after the contents of the link.

Comment: @powerbuoy note that transform or relative will only move element at screen but will not push any text that would stand behind it :)

Comment: Thank you, I was aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add :

```
position: absolute;
```

for `transform`

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/tzyorz12/1/